# Why does sbt build fail with "java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/java/bin/javac": error=20, Not a directory"?

Tags: apache-spark

I  downloaded Spark the latest version from the Spark site. I built using `sbt/sbt assembly` and faced the error:

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (streaming-flume-sink/compile:compile) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/java/bin/javac": error=20, Not a directory
[error] (unsafe/compile:compile) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/java/bin/javac": error=20, Not a directory
[error] (network-common/compile:compile) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/java/bin/javac": error=20, Not a directory
[error] (launcher/compile:compile) java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/java/bin/javac": error=20, Not a directory
[error] Total time: 3438 s, completed Sep 11, 2015 1:38:03 AM
```

What can be the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: What version of Spark do you use? What package did you download from the site? What sbt command have you executed? Do you have `java` installed on your machine? Can you execute `java -version` from the cmd you use to build Spark? There's a pre-compiled version of Spark on the site you should rather use.

Comment: Version of spark is: 1.5.0, Yes I have Java installed on my machine: root@localhost:/usr/bin# java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27).    See Spark is taking wrong path of Java.Its taking Java from /usr/bin/java/bin/javac .It is actually present at: /usr/bin/javac. Also I have tried the precompiled version, there it takes from /usr/bin/java/bin/java. Its a similar problem in both cases
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

Comment: Also JAVA_HOME is set correctly as:       root@localhost:/home/sujay/Spark/spark-1.5.0# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/bin/java

Comment: I still have not found any solution to the above problem . I also tried the precompiled version of Apache Spark and found the same problem.Why is Spark configured to take Java from : /usr/bin/java/bin/java.  This seems strange and ridiculous as by default Java is present at /usr/bin/java and all software systems use Java from this path.Really seems so awkward that a world class cluster computing software looks for Java at an unusual path

Comment: Same story! Did the same thing! Still getting the same error!

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr** Unset `JAVA_HOME` and start over.

The issue is `JAVA_HOME` that points at a java executable, but should really be the installation directory of the Java runtime.

It's a common rule to use `JAVA_HOME` and resolve the jars and binaries of the Java tools like the compiler, JVM, etc. with `JAVA_HOME` as the prefix of the path. That's why you see `Cannot run program "/usr/bin/java/bin/javac": error=20, Not a directory` since your `JAVA_HOME` resolves to `/usr/bin/java`.

Comment: Oh Yes.That sounds good.Will try it out.I still dont know why JAVA_HOME was set to /usr/bin/java

Answer (score 0):

put the java path

"""
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.16.0.8-1.amzn2.0.1.x86_64

""" in the Jenkins management

[JAVA_HOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtXIK.png)